# Edit module records redirects me to Dashboard

Tags: magento2

I am developing my 1st module for Magento 2.
It's a simple module showing a list of records from a db table which can be edited, opening a form.

The problem i have is that each time i am trying to edit a record redirects me to the dashboard.
I disabled the keys from the urls and is working fine without the keys.

Does anyone has a clue why this could happen?

Answer (score 1):

Found and solved.
In the grid's xml the url to the edit action was missing the reference to my module.
Although the missing part was auto-populated seems like it is somehow validated based on the layout.

So i changed:

```
<item name="base" xsi:type="string">/*/edit</item>
```

to

```
<item name="base" xsi:type="string">mymodule/*/edit</item>
```